# In java how to get all values for a given key in multimap?

Tags: java, multimap

In java,want to get the values for a given key in multimap of guava and apache commons.
say 
MultiMap dbOutput and now want to get all the values for the key "key" which is present in dbOutput.

Comment: Which MultiMap? Guava? Your own?

Comment: You can google for *how to implement multimap*. In case you are using given solution for such collection, it most likely has `get` method which returns array of values for a given key

Answer (score 1):

If this multiMap is guaua multimap then All the values can be retrieved in the form of collection using Multimap.get(key).

For more details please go through below link:
https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're talking about Guava. Please, refer to [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multimap-guava-java/) about Guava MultiMap. It provides a `get(Key k)` method to retrieve a collection of all values assigned to the given key.

Regards,